# how to generate random numbers in a specific range in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

clickhouse only has a few random functions like rand(). but, how can i create random numbers under a specific range. let's say create numbers in the range of 0-50
for example something like:

```
select rand(0,50) as random_0_50
```

| random_0_50 |
| --- |
| 5 |
| 12 |
| 32 |
| 0 |
| 27 |

Answer (score 2):

clickhouse lets you run module function under select.
so u can decide your range x by using `select rand() % x`

in the case about the code will be:

```
select rand() % 50 random_0_50
```

Answer (score 0):

Clickhouse has built-in generateRandom() function that helps quickly generate and populate data
Here is an article with this function https://medium.com/p/45e92c2645c5

Comment: Thanks, but it's a little bit different

Answer (score 0):

`rand` function returns a number between `[0 : 4294967295]`. You can get modulo of it to constrain between the numbers you want like this:

```sql
SELECT rand() % 51 AS random_0_50

Query id: e4addce1-37b2-44a7-ab51-f37b6ef4ff58

┌─random_0_50─┐
│          13 │
└─────────────┘
```

Or you can create a function for it:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION rand_range AS (lower_bound, upper_bound) -> (lower_bound + (rand() % (upper_bound + 1)))

SELECT rand_range(0, 50) AS random_0_50

Query id: 9efa566d-e825-4e34-b228-e6ba6e210b16

┌─random_0_50─┐
│          50 │
└─────────────┘
```